# Странная работа функции std::lower_bound

Tags: c++

Использую функцию std::lower_bound. Он вроде возвращает итератор на элемент не меньший заданному.

Вот, что возвращает данный код:

1 -1 3 -1 5 -1 7 8 -1 -1

По идее, он должен элемент B[2] заменить на -1, но он это делает с элементом B[9]. Почему?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> B{1, -1, 3, -1, 5, -1, 7, 8, -1, 10};
    std::vector<int>::iterator j = std::lower_bound(B.begin(), B.end(), 3);
    *j = -1;
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
        std::cout << B[k] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эта функция заточена под отсортированный массив и только под него. Там бинарный поиск внутри.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прочтите внимательно [описание `lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) - он работает с **упорядоченными последовательностями**. Ваша таковой не является.

Comment: Точно, спасибо) Изначально была упорядоченная, просто добавила -1